# What should be used for waiting users in the pool

Tags: java, jsp

I am developing a JSP web where I need to use a pool of users.

**That means:**
If any user clicks on some button it should add him to a waiting list and waits until there is another user doing the same thing. After another person comes it will pair them.

I did not know how to find it so I am asking it here.

**CODE:**
This is happening after clicking on the button

```
<body>
<%@page import ="main.Person" %>
<%Person person= new Person(5);%>
<%=person.findAPair() %>
</body>
```

What should be in the class Person to find a pair and how to connect it is thing that I haven't thought about yet but you can give me any suggestion.

**But the main thing is how to add the person to the pool and after finding the pair, remove from the pool.**

For more info just ask, I can edit the question.

EDIT:

I was thinking, would it be ok just to add the waiting people to an array? Or should they be placed to database (I think it is not neccessary, is it?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) of users. When there is more than one user in the stack (length > 1) you could `.pop()` the users off the stack. This would work well because when you `.push()` a user onto the stack he/she would be last to be popped off (creating the order of pairs you want).

**Logic:**

1. User clicks button
2. User gets put in stack
3. Check if stack.length > 1
4. If true, pop() twice and pair users, if false go to 1

Comment: Nice, that could be the answer I am gonna try it, thanks. Do you have any idea how, after the pairing thing, can I inform both with the same message? I mean how to track them or something?

Comment: @OndrejTokar , don't forget to click the check mark under the arrows if this is the answer you were looking for. And I am not sure how you are trying to track the users, so I am not sure how you would alert them.

Comment: I am not that new at SO I know how to mark the answer no worries I just want to wait for another suggestions.